# Laravel 5.6 recuperar dados de um formulario?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

**Erro**

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>
> No message

**Método no Controller**

```
class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    public function post(Request $request){
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $senha = $request->input('senha');

    dd($email,$senha);
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/post', 'GuzzleController@post');
```

**index.php**

*Obs: aqui que fico perdido*

```
<body>
    <form action="/post" method="POST">
         E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>   
         senha: <input type="text" name="senha"><br>
         <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Porque você está editando seu index.php?

Comment: Não entendi  a sua pergunta

Comment: Sua view se chama `ìndex.php`? Ela está dentro da pasta public esse html ?

Comment: não , e so um nome que coloquei padrão , dentro de \resources\views\index\index.blade.php

Comment: quando eu chamo o `método` la no `controller` e tento buscar os dados do formulario ele da este erro , `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message`

Comment: Altera a tua rota para post: Route::post

Comment: @diegoViera opa , alterei e mudou o erro agora esta `The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.` ja fechei tudo e abri novamente , ja reiniciei o server

Comment: Não está faltando uma  `}` para fechar a `function` `post` no `GuzzleController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nas rotas altere dessa forma

```
Route::any('/post', 'GuzzleController@post')->name('postForm');
```

O `Route::any` ira pegar todos os métodos e como você quer apenas o *POST* pode colocar

```
Route::post
```

Outra coisa boa é colocar um nome nas suas rotas, dessa forma você poderá alterar a URL dinamicamente, sem ter que alterar em vários arquivos.

Não se esqueça do *CSRF token*, é necessário no Laravel, em requisições *POST*

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('postForm')}}">
@csrf
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>   
     senha: <input type="text" name="senha"><br>
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Experimente colocar o nome da *view* como `index.blade.php`

Comment: Ótima Explicação , consegui entender ! , só tive que alterar uma coisa  para funcionar , tentei usar `action="{{route('/post')}}">` ele diz que `n("Route [{$name}] not defined.");` então eu  fiz direto `action="/post"`

Comment: o helper route() permite apenas chamar o nome da rota

Comment: Exemplo 
Route::any('/post', 'GuzzleController@post')->name('postForm');
veja no final o método name();
ai na route você chama
route('postForm')

Comment: Assim quando alterar a url da sua rota não será necessário ficar atualizando no código